# Is gnome-terminal falsifiable on most debian-based systems?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

I'm writing an application for debian-based linux systems.

I want to know if i can safely add gnome-terminal as a dependency in my application.

In other words:

Do all debian-based systems allow users to install the 'gnome-terminal' package (if not, which systems do not allow it?)

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: What functionality do you need which is missing from something basic like `xterm`? In many cases a simple console script is better, and users can decide for themselves whether they want or need a graphical interface on top.

Comment: On Debian, `x-terminal-emulator` runs whichever graphical terminal the user configured via preferences. You could also depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like a great idea: look at the [jungle of dependencies](http://deps.scarydevilmonastery.net/gnome-terminal.svg) this will introduce.
You may not notice if you have gnome installed already, but for anybody who hasn't, the number of dependecies would in many cases result in people simply not installing your application, rather than putting up with all those dependencies. "Allowed" doesn't mean "desirable".